# Can I leave the EU on my New Zealand passport, having come in with my European passport and lost it?

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, dual-nationality, eu-citizens

Will there be problems if it hasn't been stamped in?

Comment: Yes, the lack of an entry record it will almost certainly be noticed.  Since you do have a valid NZ passport, the airline will be fine and I *suspect* EU immigration would also be OK if you explain what happened (you'll want a police report for the loss!), but I recommend you ring up your local immigration dept and confirm.

Comment: Are you in the Schengen area or in another EU country? Have you staid longer than what is allowed as a NZ citizen? Have you consider getting a replacement for your EU passport before going back to NZ? Depending on the circumstances, that might be the solution with least hassle.

Comment: The duration of stay shouldn't matter, because the only way to get around the absence of an entry record is going to be to convince the officials that the traveler is an EU citizen.

Comment: @phoog It is not *that* uncommon, that non-EEA citizens have to leave the Schengen area without an entry stamp. If a regular non-EEA tourist looses his passport while visiting the Schengen area and gets a new passport from his home country's embassy to get back home, he would more or less be in the same situation, lacking any official trace of his entry. There are of course procedures in place to cope with this situation and it is usually sufficient to show a flight ticket or similar as a replacement proof of the last date of entry.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo that's true, but in such cases the passport would normally have been issued within the previous 90 days, which this one probably wasn't. But more importantly, regardless of the reason for having a third-country passport with no entry stamp, someone in that situation will get extra scrutiny, at which point the reason will come out. Since, in this case, the reason is that the person is an EU citizen, the duration of stay in the EU will not affect the outcome.

Comment: @phoog It is not likely that OP can prove being an EU citizen when passing exit immigration checks without getting a new EU passport, in which case the problem is moot anyway. If he hasn't staid longer than a NZ citizen is allowed to, his EU citizenship will be irrelevant and will not have to be proven. *Why* the entry stamp is missing (the immigration officer could also simply have forgotten to stamp the passport at the entry check) is of less importance if OP with other means can show at which date he entered.

Answer (score 1):

You can leave the EU, including Schengen, Ireland and the UK with just showing your New Zealand passport to the airline while checking in and leaving.

If you leave the Schengen area, you will pass through exist passport control. They might ask you about your missing entry stamp, so prepare for that.
If you still have your boarding cards from your flights to arrive in Europe, or can get copies from the mail or phone app, have them at hand.
If you have any proof you are an EU citizen, like an ID card, bring that. Also bring the police report that you have reported your passport lost.
Make sure you arrive at the airport early, as you may be asked to step in a separate room to be questioned.

I am not sure what is the best but I think I would approach the officer with 'I lost my (country name) passport but here is my NZ passport, which was not stamped as I handed the other one coming in.'

Comment: While somewhat tangential to the question, this assumes that the airline will allow the OP to board his flight based on his New Zealand passport.